# TestBed: No provider for EffectsRootModule

Tags: angular

I have this module:

```
import { EffectsModule } from '@ngrx/effects';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [MyComponent],
  imports: [
    EffectsModule.forFeature([MyEffect]),
  ],
})
export class MyModule { }
```

and I want inport it into TestBed

```
import { MyModule} from './my.module';

describe('MyTest', () => {

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        MyModule
      ]
    });
  });
});
```

but it raise an exception:

> NullInjectorError:
> R3InjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[EffectsFeatureModule ->
> EffectsRootModule -> EffectsRootModule]:    NullInjectorError: No
> provider for EffectsRootModule!

Comment: import the EffectsModule in the spec, too.

Comment: Also, when you're importing that module, you're importing nothing. When you import the module, you import what the module exports and it is exporting nothing.

Comment: @R.Richards thanks... work with `EffectsModule.forRoot()`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try to add to your imports:

```
imports: [
  EffectsModule.forRoot([])
]
```